# Axon Token [IndexTrackingToken{globalIndex=2}] is of the wrong type

Tags: axon

I am changing from axon 2 to axon 4 where I am using spring boot based configuration with axon-spring-boot and mysql DB .

In my application properties 
I have added this configuration

```
axon.serializer.general = XSTREAM
axon.serializer.events= XSTREAM`enter code here`
axon.serializer.messages=XSTREAM
```

Here is the Exception I am getting in the logs

```
org.axonframework.eventhandling.TrackingEventProcessor Error occurred. Starting retry mode.
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Token [IndexTrackingToken{globalIndex=2}] is of the wrong type. Expected [GapAwareTrackingToken]
    at org.axonframework.common.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:56)
    at org.axonframework.eventsourcing.eventstore.jpa.JpaEventStorageEngine.fetchTrackedEvents(JpaEventStorageEngine.java:137)
    at org.axonframework.eventsourcing.eventstore.BatchingEventStorageEngine.lambda$readEventData$1(BatchingEventStorageEngine.java:123)
    at org.axonframework.eventsourcing.eventstore.BatchingEventStorageEngine$EventStreamSpliterator.tryAdvance(BatchingEventStorageEngine.java:236)
    at java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.lambda$initPartialTraversalState$0(StreamSpliterators.java:294)
    at java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$AbstractWrappingSpliterator.fillBuffer(StreamSpliterators.java:206)
    at java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$AbstractWrappingSpliterator.doAdvance(StreamSpliterators.java:161)
    at java.util.stream.StreamSpliterators$WrappingSpliterator.tryAdvance(StreamSpliterators.java:300)
    at java.util.Spliterators$1Adapter.hasNext(Spliterators.java:681)
    at org.axonframework.eventsourcing.eventstore.EmbeddedEventStore$EventConsumer.peekPrivateStream(EmbeddedEventStore.java:397)
    at org.axonframework.eventsourcing.eventstore.EmbeddedEventStore$EventConsumer.peek(EmbeddedEventStore.java:356)
    at org.axonframework.eventsourcing.eventstore.EmbeddedEventStore$EventConsumer.hasNextAvailable(EmbeddedEventStore.java:333)
    at org.axonframework.common.stream.BlockingStream.hasNextAvailable(BlockingStream.java:40)
    at org.axonframework.eventhandling.TrackingEventProcessor.checkSegmentCaughtUp(TrackingEventProcessor.java:270)
    at org.axonframework.eventhandling.TrackingEventProcessor.processBatch(TrackingEventProcessor.java:216)
    at org.axonframework.eventhandling.TrackingEventProcessor.processingLoop(TrackingEventProcessor.java:181)
    at org.axonframework.eventhandling.TrackingEventProcessor$TrackingSegmentWorker.run(TrackingEventProcessor.java:661)
    at org.axonframework.eventhandling.TrackingEventProcessor$WorkerLauncher.run(TrackingEventProcessor.java:771)
    at org.axonframework.eventhandling.TrackingEventProcessor$CountingRunnable.run(TrackingEventProcessor.java:588)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you see is the `JpaEventStorageEngine` complaining you are giving it a `GlobalSequenceTrackingToken` (the `GlobalSequenceTrackingToken`'s `toString()` method states `"IndexTrackingToken{" + "globalIndex=" + globalIndex + '}'`), whilst it requires the `GapAwareTrackingToken`.

The likely scenario why this occurred is that you initially started your application with Axon Server, which uses the `GlobalSequenceTrackingToken`, and are now moving away from Axon Server as your event store towards a personally maintained RDBMS set up using JPA.

How I see it, you've got two ways to go about this:

1. Keep using Axon Server, as this safes time when it comes to configuring a database (as you don't have to configure it at all), which will also solve this discrepancy.
2. Drop the existing `GlobalSequenceTrackingToken`s from your `token_entry` table so that Axon can replace them for the `GapAwareTrackingToken`.

Assuming you are consciously moving away from Axon Server, I'd think you'll opt for option 2. In doing so it might be beneficial to initialize your `GapAwareTrackingToken`s to start at the same point the `GlobalSequenceTrackingToken`s are at.

Look at the `TrackingEventProcessorConfiguration` to specifying the initial token for a given Tracking Event Processor.

If you're still in development phase of the migration, I assume you can drop these tokens altogether to safe time.

Comment: Thanks Steven, indeed that was the problem I cleaned up my token_entry table and it worked

Comment: After I drop the tokens it worked but while restarting my application its getting stacked on creating the saga, but if I drop token_event entry again its working, how can I avoid this problem while going with option 2

Comment: You can initialize a Tracking Token at different positions in the Event Stream.
How to do this is described in the Reference Guide: https://docs.axoniq.io/reference-guide/configuring-infrastructure-components/event-processing/event-processors#custom-tracking-token-position

Comment: I have added those token, then my scheduled events are not working typically getting this error message org.axonframework.eventsourcing.eventstore.EventStoreException: An event with identifier [a1c5cd45-1262-4f13-944f-0022db96b1c0] could not be persisted

Comment: To better assist you with the event scheduling issues, I would suggest to start a new question @Dawit